# Remember how far you've gotten when crunching a big MSSQL table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

We have a application that executes a job to process a range of rows from a mssql view.
This view contains *a lot* of rows, and the data is inserted with a additional column (dataid) set to identity, meant for us to use to know how far through the dataset we have gotten.

A while ago we had some issues when just getting top n rows with a dataid larger than y (y being the last biggest last dataid that we processed). It seemed that the rows was not returned in correct order, meaning that when we grabbed a range of rows, it seemed that the dataid of some of the rows was misplaced, which meant that we processed a row with a dataid of 100 when we actually had only gotten to 95.

**example**

The window / range is 100 rows on each crunch. but if the rows' dataid are not in sequential order, the query getting the next 100 rows, may contain a dataid that really should have been located in the next crunch. And then rows will be skipped when the next crunch is executed.

A order by on the dataid would solve the problem, but that is way way to slow.
Do you guys have any suggestions how this could be done in a better/working way?

When i say a lot of rows, i mean a few billion rows, and yes, if you think that is absolutely crazy you are completely right!

We use Dapper to map the rows into objects.
This is completely read only.

I hope this question is not too vague.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an index on `dataid`? Is it an indexed view?

Comment: We do, and the performance was pretty good, with around 700 mio rows, but the performance has been really really database-breaking bad in the last few days. I don't know if the index has been updated/rebuilt, but i will find out if that is the case. The database is remote so i don't have access, and i don't know what kinds of operations has been running on it, if new data has been added, etc.

Comment: you need to look at the Actual Execution Plan as suggested my the answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/16539083/659190

Answer (score 2):

> A order by on the dataid would solve the problem, but that is way way to slow.

Apply the proper indexes.

The only answer to "why is my query slow" is: [How To: Optimize SQL Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650689.aspx).

Comment: tagged as MS SQL server, so a query plan would be more appropriate. Same concept.

Comment: We already have a index on the dataid column used when ordering, when we added the index, it seemed to be quite fast, but not anymore, could a rebuild of the index fix this? and how fast should a index on the correct column make it? I mean, how many rows can a ms sql server handle when the proper indices are added?

Comment: @Module its a function of your hardware, but generally lots.

Answer (score 1):

Is not clear what you mean by mixing 'view' and 'insert' in the same sentence. If you really mean a view that *projects* an [`IDENTITY` *function*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) then you can stop right now, it will not work. You need to have a **persisted** bookmark to resume your work. An IDENTITY projected in a SELECT by a view does not meet the persistence criteria.

You need to process data in a well defined order **that is persistent on consecutive reads**. You must be able to read a key that clearly defines a boundary in the given order. You need to persist the last key processed in the same transaction as the batch processing the rows. How you achieve these requirements, is entirely up to you. A typical solution is to process in the **clustered index order** and remember the last processed cluster key position. An unique clustered key is a must. An [`IDENTITY` *property*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and a clustered index by it *does* satisfy the criteria you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to work on the last 100, give a take a 1000000, you could look at partitioning the data.

Whats the point of including the other 999999000000 in the index?